# Conditional cv qualifier in function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to make a method conditionally const. That is, we have

```
template <bool isConst>
class A {
    // stuff
};
```

depending on the value of the template parameter, either

```
void method() const;
```

or

```
void method();
```

appear in the body of `A`.

My first thought was to try conditional types, but this does not work, for obvious reasons.

Comment: What condition exactly? And is that method part of a `template<typename T> struct something`?

Comment: Thanks. I added some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is a specialization:

```
template<bool>
struct A
{
    void method() const
    {
        std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct A<false>
{
    void method()
    {
        std::cout << "non-const" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and in case you have more methods and don't want to duplicate them, make `A` a base class `A_base` and derive your `A` from it. (I added this to the live example below)

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c11ef8768bdc21c6)

Comment: Thanks! I figured specialization would be one way; I was looking for a quick one-liner (like the ```std::conditional``` for ```typedef```s). I think this might be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is only intended for interests' sake. I don't suggest actually doing this in a commercial product. Maybe in a personal project if you're trying out things.

Something you could do, which is a little hacky, is this:

```
template< bool OnlyConst >
class TestClass
{
  struct Placeholder {};
public:

  template< class T >
  typename std::enable_if< OnlyConst && !std::is_same<T, Placeholder>::value, void >::type 
    MyFunc() const 
  { std::cout << "Const version"; }

  template< class T >
  typename std::enable_if< !OnlyConst && !std::is_same<T, Placeholder>::value, void >::type 
    MyFunc() 
  { std::cout << "Nonconst version"; }
};
```

The unfortunate bit is that the functions do need to be templated to use the enable_if, and if you have nothing to do with that template then the caller is still going to need to provide it so the compiler can 'use' it. You can't use a default template parameter for T either.

If you could find a use for T that would let the compiler automatically determine its type then it would work out well.

Right now you'd have to always give a value for T when calling:

```
test.MyFunc<void>(); // even though the void doesn't affect it at all
```

The placeholder struct is only there because SFINAE (at least on VS2012) seems to want T to be part of the determination of whether the function can be instantiated or not. So the is_same call is pretty much just for sticking some usage of T in the enable_if.

I have done a spot of testing with the above code in VS2012 and it seems to work.

Comment: I don't know in short. At least for VS2012 I am able to call as: test.MyFunc<void>() and the compiler seems happy enough that T is being used in std::is_same. So as I said in the answer it does mean that the compiler is going to want to know T at calling time even though it ultimately has no use. If T could be used somehow then it can be deduced and the caller won't have to specify it. Or am I not understanding what you are saying?

Comment: OK, your answer makes sense and provides another idea for OP, so +1 although the `MyFunc<void>` still seems a bit awkward to me :)

Comment: +1 for the ingenuity, but unfortunately, templating with <void> is a bit awkward for me too.

Comment: Sorry - I've been trying to find a way that the void can be gotten rid of. I knew it was a fools errand to begin with. I wondered a bit about whether using or typedef might come in handy for the < void >. However I don't think they can be made to do it. Anyway interesting exercise.

Comment: I think `template <bool B = OnlyConst> typename std::enable_if<B>::type MyFunc() const` would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Casey for some reason my VS2012 doesn't like that at all. I did try it but it errors with "default template arguments are only allowed on a class template". Perhaps this is just a remnant of earlier times, and if I had VS2013 it might not complain as such.